# Is the Fano Plane Pappian?

Tags: finite-fields, projective-geometry

This might not be a well-informed question, but I started reading a bit about projective planes, and the following question occured to me:

Does Pappus's theorem hold in the Fano Plane?

Since the Fano Plane is the projective plane over $GF(2)$ which is commutative, then (if I understand correctly) it should be Pappian. But a Pappian configuration has 9 lines and 9 points, while the Fano Plane only has 7 lines and 7 points. So how could Pappus's theorem hold in the Fano Plane?

Comment: [Pappus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem) only requires two sets of three collinear points, $A,B,C$ and $a,b,c$ to be described. The other constructed points need not be distinct from these. You only need $A$ distinct fom $b,c$, $B$ distinct from $a,c$ and $C$ distinct from $a,b$ to be able to describe the diagram. Anyway, theorems are also sometimes *vacuously true* in that conditions are never satisfied, and the claim is thus correct.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that it holds (but in a degenerate form). Thank you!